# Windows 10, VS 2015, unable to start debugging WindowsPhone 8.0 app on emulator/device

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, windows-phone-8.1, windows-10, emulation

I have a fresh Windows 10 install, fresh VS2015 install.

Windows 8.1 emulators are installed, they startup as expected and they can see the internet. So far so good.

Compiling and deploying the Windows Phone 8.0 (silverlight) application works fine, however, debugging refuses to start with the message:

Status bar: Launching TaskHost.exe failed.
Popup: The application could not be launched for debugging. Ensure that the target device screen is unlocked and that the application is installed.

I have checked (the obvious) and the device\emulator is unlocked and I can physically run the app that was deployed when the debugging session was attempted - so I know its installed. Confirmed by uninstalling and re-deploying.

The same error occurs with the emulator AND the device. I can debug normal (non windows phone) applications just fine.

Output logs:

```
2>------ Deploy started: Project: {APPNAME}.WinPhone, Configuration: Debug x86 ------
2>Deploying F:\TFS\{PATH}\x86\Debug\{APPNAME}.WinPhone_Debug_x86.xap...
2>Connecting to Emulator 8.1 WVGA 4 inch 512MB...
2>The application is already installed on the device. Checking if an incremental deployment is possible...
2>Doing incremental deployment...
2>Updating information related to modified files...
2>Deployment of F:\TFS\{PATH}\x86\Debug\{APPNAME}.WinPhone_Debug_x86.xap succeeded.
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 1 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Deploy: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Does your PC has Hyper-V enabled?

Comment: @Alexej yes, hyper-v is enabled and the emulator works perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here ended up being that that Hyper-V Administrators group did not exist. This is a known problem with a particular (early) version of Windows 10.

The only way to fix it was a rebuild of the machine.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the following in your code:

```
// Avoid screen locks while debugging.
if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
{
    PhoneApplicationService.Current.UserIdleDetectionMode = IdleDetectionMode.Disabled;
}
```

From: https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/apps/ff402572(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: How would this help? The debugger wont connect to the device or emulator at all - the app never even starts! Update: I tested this, on the off chance that it would do some magic, and it didn't work.

Comment: The reason for this is, that if you attach the debugger to an emulator, that the emulator kind of shuts down the connection whilst locking the screen and so on....which detaches your debugger. For the apps I delevoped this works fine